# Consecutive Double Preposition "In" in "took the letters in in the morning"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction

In the story of  [“A Case of Identity” by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/32/the-adventures-of-sherlock-holmes/347/adventure-3-a-case-of-identity/), there is a line -

> I took the letters **in in** the morning, so there was no need for father
>   to know. “Were you engaged to the gentleman at this time?”

Can anyone explain how preposition "in" used consecutively in the clause "**in in** the morning" grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

"Take in" is a phrasal verb, probably meaning that the speaker took the letters into the house.  "In the morning" is a prepositional phrase, telling what time of day that action occurred.
So it is a rearrangement of "***In*** the morning, I took the letters ***in***, so there was no need for father to know."

Answer (score 0):

> *I took the letters in* [*in the morning*]*, so there was no need for*
>   *father to know.*

The two prepositions may be consecutive, but they are separate constituents.

The first "in" is a particle (a preposition) serving as complement of "took", with the intervening NP “the letters” serving as direct object of “took”.

The PP "in the morning" is a temporal adjunct, an optional item in the structure of the clause.